# devise and current_user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-plugins

i have a question about devise system.

my last ruby project was done with nifty:authnentication. With nifty, i can manage session for current_user and other information from '"controller_authentication.rb"'. But now, i want to add a new current_* information.

I want to know where i can find current_user method? where is it defined?

with nifty i used something like

```
@current_company ||= Company.find(session[:company_id]) if session[:company_id]
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` is defined as a helper in devise source code. When you install devise on your project, it gets activated too.

Comment: as a helper? i have no helper named session, devise or user in my app. Is it somewhere else?

Comment: @neimad: `session` is a Rails method, `devise` is a Devise method and where are you seeing user?

Comment: hmm i'm not sure i understand what you asking? Where i see user?

Comment: `session` is managed in Rails internals, `devise` and `user` in devise.

Comment: Ah, yes i know, but, previously, with nifty authentication, i have just modified control_authentication.rb to add what i need. I need to create a new global variable (method?) when a user log in. like current_user, i want to create a current_company, etc. But i'm unable to find where current_user are created when we log in.

Comment: You don't need to know where it is. You can just define a new helper containing `current_user.company` for instance.

Comment: Ok, thanks i can now add current_company. but how to manage log-in? with application helper too? if i want to redirect user to his company when he log-in? in helper, i must def a method right? how to set log-in redirect_to? thanks for your support

Comment: You can use the route to your company like [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) to redirect the user to his company after sign-in.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is the subdomain isnt attached to the user, but to the company attached to the user. the git rails-subdomain-devise cant help me too. I already tried this git, and no success. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` is defined dynamically in Devise.  Since your user model could actually be a different model, the method uses your model name for 'mapping' when it defines the current_whatever helper method:

```
def current_#{mapping}
    @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(:scope => :#{mapping})
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L123